# User intentions analysis

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, enterprise

I'm going to work on some project that would do a user-action recognition based on what he/she does in the system.

As far as I understand there are two main parts here :

- intercept the user actions (say http traffic in web/ui interaction in thick-client)
- analysis of user intentions

While the first part is rather technical and therefor easy to implement,
the second one is AI related and can be academic.

So I was wondering whether someone knows some third-parties/academic projects that would implement the 'action-recognition' stuff.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Probably more a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Unless this is for educational purpose, machine learning may not always be best approach to solve your problem.

Comment: @dystroy - thanks a lot, I wasn't aware of this site, I'll try asking there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe - [Apache Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/) could help you. Look towards to collaborative filtering part of this framework.